# Convert text file all data to xml format in java

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a text file and i need to convert this text file all data in xml format to make more readable.

[Text file](http://android.gameplanpilot.com/dropBox/video/My-Videos/01%20SD%20CUTUP%20DUKE%20VS%20CINCINNATI%20122712a.cutup)

how can i convert it in xml format.

Any java library or any way that i can do it.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is rather vague (and you could probably find the answer yourself with just a little research), but I'll give you a hint.

Your sample appears to be an INI file (as traditionally used for configuration files on Windows & DOS). So, look for an "INI file parser." If you can't find one, you should be able to write a simple parser yourself using regular expressions. It's a simple file format, consisting of section headings like [SectionTitle] and data fields like Key=Value. That's all.

As for generating XML ... it shouldn't be hard, but "xml format" is not a useful description. Can you be more specific? E.g., what will the XML be used for?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=Main_Page. I've used it and it's great.

A more sophisticated solution would be to use [Mule Data Mapper.](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Datamapper+User+Guide+and+Reference) On the server side, obviously.